# ember.js - render a template in router.js equivalent for controllers

Tags: templates, model-view-controller, ember.js

In ember, is there a way to render a template into an outlet from a controller to get the desired effect of:

```
this.render('some_template', {
  into: 'template_name',
  outlet: 'template_outlet'
});
```

Or better yet, call an action in router.js from a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put a method in the corresponding route to the controller under the actions hash (Example: posts.index controller and posts.index route) and call it using send

posts.index controller

```
this.send('exampleAction', record);
```

posts.index route

```
actions: {
  exampleAction: function(record){
       console.log(record);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outlet, you can use a component:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-outlet">
  {{ partial template }}
</script>
```

Then, in your controller, you can have a `template` property that you can pass to the component to display your template dynamically:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  template: function(){
    return 'this_one';
  }.property(),

  actions: {
    that_one: function(){
      this.set('template', 'that_one');
    }
  }
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dugeqi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Not completely sure what you mean by

> Or better yet, call an action in router.js from a controller?

but if you are just trying to transition into a different route, you can use the `transitionToRoute()` method (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute))